# Updating a progress bar while awaiting async operation

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I try to update a progress bar while awaiting a async IO operation. The following code is doing that.

```cs
Task<string> io = SomeOperationAsync();

while(!io.IsComplete)
{
    progressBar.Value = value // add some progress;
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
}    

string result = await io;
```

This works quite ok.The Progressbar fills up quite smoothly.

But as you see, I will check for completion every 200 ms rather than really awaiting it. I might end up waiting for up to 200 ms too long.

Is there a better way to achieve this, so that my method can immediately return once the IO operation is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .[WhenAny()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=net-7.0) to return when any task completes. A small refactor to your code would return if the primary task finishes before the delay.

```cs
Task<string> io = SomeOperationAsync();

while(!io.IsComplete)
{
    progressBar.Value = value // add some progress;
    await Task.WhenAny(io, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)));
}    

string result = await io;
```

Comment: Surprisingly easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, have `SomeOperationAsync` report its progress directly using [the standard progress reporting pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#progress-reporting-optional?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058). Then, reporting progress while awaiting the call is super simple:

```
var progress = new Progress<TValue>(value => progressBar.Value = value);
string result = await SomeOperationAsync(progress);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75536365/11178549) solution is the most practical one, but you may also want to know the most efficient:

```
Task<string> io = SomeOperationAsync();

using PeriodicTimer timer = new(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));

_ = io.ContinueWith(_ => timer.Dispose(), CancellationToken.None,
    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);

while (true)
{
    await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync();
    if (io.IsCompleted) break;
    progressBar.Value = value // add some progress;
}    

string result = await io;
```

The [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer) will tick consistently every 200 msec, until it is disposed, in which case the `WaitForNextTickAsync` will complete immediately with the result `false`.

In general I avoid fire-and-forget tasks like the `ContinueWith` above, but in this case the associated risk is negligible. Worst case scenario, the loop will complete 200 msec too late. As long as the `io.IsCompleted` is checked inside the loop, there is no risk of an infinite loop.

Comment: I haven't seen `ContinueWith` in a while and great use of the new .NET 6 timer! Is there a chance it can be disposed whilst you're awaiting?

Comment: @itsdaniel0 yes, disposing the `PeriodicTimer` while a `WaitForNextTickAsync` is pending is OK. This class never throws `ObjectDisposedException`s.